# Simple Membership:Last Login date of User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the simple membership in my asp.net MVC 4 application. How i can get the Last Login date of User. I don't see the date is created in default webpages schema table? Do i need to create the field for the LastLogin date in simple Membership?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved this way:

1. I  added a LastLogin field to UserProfile Model in UsersContext:

   ```
   [Table("UserProfile")]
   public class UserProfile 
   {    
       [Key]    
       [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
       public virtual DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. I modified the Login Method in AccountController :

   ```
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
   {            
       if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))     
       {
           using (UsersContext db=new UsersContext())                
           {
               UserProfile  userProfile = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.UserName==model.UserName);
               userProfile.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
               db.Entry(userProfile).State=EntityState.Modified;
               db.SaveChanges();
           }

           return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
3. Then I fetched  UserProfiles Like the way bellow:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View("Index",_db.UserProfiles);
   }
   ```
4. Finally, I displayed LastLogin DateTime in Index.cshtml:

   ```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
           </td>  
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastLogin)
           </td>
       </tr>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Babul Mirdha. I will solve the same way. I thought there might be something in single membership provider similar to the asp.net membership. In asp.net membership it has the lastlogin property and gives us the record updates the lastlogin

Comment: Welcome, Gayatri, yea, There is lastlogin property is Asp.Net memberbership. So I was also Expecting that LastLogin property in SimpleMembership in MVC4 but I did not get it till now ..., so I solved this way, Thanks.

Comment: Why is this LastLogin field declared as "virtual"?

Comment: Virtual Keyword is used for Lazy Loading & More efficient change tracking. You can use virtual for each property to keep change tracking of an Object.