# How save the time of last log in using the SimpleMembership?

Tags: simplemembership

I need to save the time, when user loged in.

First I try to realize it in AccountController Login. But now I know, that isn't possible, because User.Id is -1.

Ok, and what can I do to save the time in my user table?

The next problem for me is, when do it. The informations I need to get the user are created after redirect. And the redirect can go everywhere.

An idea is, to get the time on which the ASPXAUTH cookie is set, but I don't know, how to get it.

Is there any solution?

Comment: you need to extend your userprofile model.

Comment: You want the time the user *Last Logged In* or was *Last online*?

Comment: The userprofile, my table, has fields for all I need, but I don't know when and how to fill them.

Comment: Because I use Form Authentication I need the time for successful log in.

Comment: Are you using the MembershipProvider or SimpleMembershipProvider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Membership:Last Login date of User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321696/simple-membershiplast-login-date-of-user)

Comment: I use the default of MVC 4: SimpleMembershipProvider!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only last login time, you may receive that infrimation from SimpleMembership:

```
var User = Membership.GetUser("Username") // get user by name
DateTime LastActivityDate = User.LastActivityDate; // get last activity date and time
DateTime LastLogin = User.LastLoginDate; // Last login date and time
DateTime LastPasswordChange = User.LastPasswordChangedDate;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. Before that I looked into the database and found no columns for LastActivityDate or LastLoginDate. So don't wonder that LastActivityDate and LastLoginDate are DateTime.MinValue. I found nothing, that SimpleMembership (MVC 4) use all feature of Membership.

Comment: @user2784409 Do you have aspnet_Membership table in your database? It contains all those fields.

Comment: `SimpleMembershipProvider` uses webpages_Membership.

Comment: I have an table called webpages_Membership which contains only UserId, Confirmation and 6 Password fields, not the columns you asked for. It's out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Just learning this stuff myself.

You need to extend the `AccountModel`, in `AccountModel.cs`

For example, I added Email to my UserProfile table generation.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

        public string Email { get; set; }
```

I also needed to add it to my RegisterModel further down the file

```
 public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The important part here is this new entry:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Then I needed to add the Email information to the RegisterView, which is exactly the same as doing it with the other parts, since it is now part of the model.

One of the most important parts comes when you're saving the information back into the database. In my Register Action, I have the `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` method which was already defined. It requires tweaks however, to be able to add EXTRA information to the database with this method.

Thankfully one of the overloads allows passing in a dictionary to the extra data.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, false);

new { Email = model.Email }
```

If you don't already have the column added in your database, I don't think it will pick it up. You need to make sure that column exists, so get it set up before hand.